# Android studio canary 4, gradle-4.0-rc-1 build failed with fakeOutputDirectory=null

Tags: gradle, android-studio-3.0

I am using android studio canary 4 with the following config:

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.0-rc-1-all.zip
```

Project level build file:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha4'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.2.0'
}
```

When I am trying to build the app, I got the following error.

```
Error:null value in entry: fakeOutputDirectory=null
```

I am not able to figure out the issue. any help will be appreciated

I have also tried removing

> .gradle

folder, it doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

The only instant I have seen a similar error was due to corrupted caches of Gradle. Additionally to `<root project dir>/.gradle` also delete `~/.gradle/caches` and retry. Should work again then.